# regex pattern repetition and ng-invalid

Tags: angularjs, regex, validation, ng-pattern

I have this pattern like so

```
<input name="ip" ng-pattern="/^http:\/\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+:[0-9]{4,5}/" class="form-control full-width text-right" type="text" ng-model="resource.ip"/>
```

The last part {4,5} is at least 4 and no more than 5. But when I type more than 5 integers at the end the form doesn't change to ng-invalid

This works on http://www.regexr.com/

Any idea why my input is allowing more than 5 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `$` to define the match end.

```
^http:\/\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+:[0-9]{4,5}$
```

From the *Reference > Archors > end*:

> Matches the end of the string, or the end of a line if the multiline flag (m) is enabled. This matches a position, not a character.

Comment: I feel silly, I must of tried this 10 times. I don't think I cleared my cache when I tried this. Anyways, this worked.

Comment: Haha.. It happens, but then you start to like regex in a while.